# ansible failing to remove a scheduled task

Tags: windows-10, scheduled-tasks, ansible

I have an ansible script that creates a scheduled task to uninstall some software, runs the task, and then attempts to remove it. when it attempts to remove it it hangs and then gives a read timeout error.  Here is some code i tried.

using win_shceduled_task module

```
 - name: remove scheduled task
   win_scheduled_task:
     name: taskname
     state: absent
```

tried using win_shell as well

```
- name: Remove the scheduled task
  become: yes
  become_user: SYSTEM
  become_method: runas
  win_shell: 'unregister-ScheduledTask -taskname "taskname"  -confirm:$false'
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case I was missing the `path` argument.
I assume, my definition of the task did not match with the existing task I wanted to delete. The state of the task was then correctly identified as 'absent' and no error was thrown.

```
 - name: remove scheduled task
   win_scheduled_task:
     name: taskname
     path: 'some/path'
     state: absent
```

Answer (score 0):

Is the task being marked as skipped or completed?

Try putting the debugger on in the ansible.cfg

```
[defaults]
enable_task_debugger = True
```

You could also try disabling the task first in case it's stuck in a state that wont allow deletion

`enabled: no`